# Operand data type float is invalid for '^' operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, operands

I am searching for the Float type limitation but I can't find any post for `^` operand.

I have a little mathematical phrase:

```
((@IntVar*((@FloatVar*1)/1200))*((1+((@FloatVar*1)/1200))^@IntValr))/(((1+((@FloatVar*1)/1200))^@IntVar)-1);
```

and SQL raises the error:

> The data types float and int are incompatible in the `^` operator.

after that, I changed the variable type and new formula is it:

```
((@IntVar*((@FloatVar*1)/1200))*((1+((@FloatVar*1)/1200))^@FloatValr))/(((1+((@FloatVar*1)/1200))^@FloatVar)-1);
```

But SQL raises error again:

> Operand data type float is invalid for `^` operator.

My first ask is, how to solve this error?
and after that, anybody knows limitation of operands on a float or decimal types?

Comment: my best guess is `^` doesn´t do what you guess it does [Opertators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) ;)

Comment: Are you trying to use `^` as the exponentiation operator?

Comment: @KevinEsche, why it doesn't work? it's a simple formula. could u explain me?

Comment: @Ali.azimi but a simple formula rarly uses a bitwise xor

Comment: What do you mean by limitation of operands on a float?

Comment: @Mureinik tnkx, it's useful and helpful. but for second question i need cause of that. i need a theoretical point of view.

Comment: @Ali.azimi - what the others are trying to tell you is that you're looking for [`POWER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx). Just because you're familiar with another language where `^` is the exponentiation operator, that doesn't mean that *every* programming language you work in is obligated to assign the same meaning to that character.

Comment: @KevinEsche are u thinking cause of that error is complexity of formula?

Comment: @ShakeerMirza i wanna say: operand ^ doesn't work on float and decimal types. why?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, u right. it's a good answer. tnkx

Comment: Just a side note - why `(@FloatVar*1)` when you can simply use `@FloatVar`?

Comment: Dear @ZoharPeled it's a Loan Formula and it's a variable that the variable has changed with number 1.
the real formula is @AnnualProfit*@Distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want use exponant function you must use power SQL SERVER function.

look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms174276.aspx)

Comment: Yes. As you and other friends said, It's a misunderstanding about SQL language and its operators.